# Understanding how processes work in shell

Tags: c, shell

Let suppose I have a program written in C that runs multiple processes and in the parent process I change the file descriptors of stdin and stdout to other FDs by using [`dup()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/dup.html).

My question is: is the change visible to all processes currently running, or just to the process where the change was made?

Comment: It is only visible to the process that does the `dup` and any subsequent children that are created *after* that `dup`. "do I have to set the FDs in the new process by using a pipe to communicate with the parent process". Don't know what you mean. It depends what you are trying to do overall and that picture is not clear as you have not provided the overall goal.

Comment: nevermind my second question

Comment: However you answer contradicts below's answer. You said "It is only visible to the process that does the dup and any subsequent children that are created after that dup". Below's answer says "If you redirect stdin\stdout in parent process it won't affect child processes."

Comment: @Fernando children created after will be will affected, let me elaborate down in my answer..

Comment: @Fernando That's because the answer is not that clear. It does not affect child process that exist at the time that `dup` is called but it does affect child processes created after that. Read the [fork man page](https://linux.die.net/man/2/fork) for yourself: "The child inherits copies of the parent's set of open file descriptors."

Answer (score 0):

If you redirect `stdin\stdout` in parent **process** it won't affect child processes created **before** redirection, it will only affect those created **after** redirection.
However, when it comes to **threads** if one thread closes pipe it will close in all threads (belonging to same process), if one of them redirects `stdout` it will affect all threads (belonging to same process).

```
Process A
.
.
Create Process B in process A
.
.
Create Process C in process A
.
.
Redirect stdout\stdin in process A
.
.
.
Create Process D in process A
```

B and C are not affected by process A redirecting its `stdout\stdin`.
Process D on the other hand will now share the same `stdout\stdin` that you redirected with parent.